# Dynamically reacting to changes in select

Tags: spring, select, spring-mvc, dynamic, spring-roo

I'm building a Spring MVC based webapp in which I'll be using several drop-down menus.

What I'm trying to accomplish is that when the user selects one of the available options, a description of that option will appear next to the select-tag.

```
<select name="userType">
            <c:forEach items="${userTypes}" var="userType">
                <option>${userType.userType}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select><br/><br/>
```

Next to that I  want to have a field that will display something like

```
${userType.description}
```

for each of the options in the dropdown.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks to anyone taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is more a javascript issue. well you could do it with server side but it would be overkill.

I would use cleint side javascript and jquery, change html/jsp to

```
<select id="userType" name="userType">
  <c:forEach items="${userTypes}" var="userType">
    <option value=${userType.description}>${userType.userType}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select><span id="myDivNextSelectTag></span><br/><br/>
```

... and the jquery

```
$("#userType").change(function(){
  $("#myDivNextSelectTag").html( $(this).value );
})
```

There might be some syntax errors, but you should get the idea - you could use `data html attribute` instead of `option value` aswell.

Answer (score 2):

you can implement it with javascript. i will use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in my example.

```
<select name="userType">
    <c:forEach items="${userTypes}" var="userType">
        <option value="${userType.userType}">${userType.userType}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>

<%-- hidden descriptions waiting to be shown. --%>
<c:forEach items="${userTypes}" var="userType">
    <div style="display:none" id="${userType.userType}" class="description">${userType.description}</div>
</c:forEach>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('select[name=userType]').change(function() {
        var userType = $(this).val()
        $('.description').hide();
        $('#' + userType).show();
    });
</script>
```

few things to keep in mind:

- there is no description shown initially. should be trivial to fix if required.
- i assume in my example `userType` to be unique.
- if `description` or `userType` contain html they could break your markup. consider using [`<c:out>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html)

Comment: Sadly nothing appears to change (and I'm a total noob with JQuery)... It doesn't crash or anything, just acts as if the script isn't running